# How to consider a module over the ring Q[t,t^(-1)] to be a module over the polynomial ring Q[t]?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Can we view a module over the ring $\mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$ to be a module over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[t]$?

where $\mathbb{Q}$ denote any rational number coefficients.

Comment: I vote to close this question, as it is not a research-level question, and thus not on-topic for this site. There is however a similiar site, math.stackexchenge.com with a broader scope where such a question would be welcome. For detailse please see the FAQs.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via the natural inclusion $\mathbb{Q}[t] \to \mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$: let an element of $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ act the way it does when considering it as an element of $\mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$. More generally, if you have a $B$-module $M$ and a morphisms of rings $A \to B$, then you can see $M$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: Of course this is a correct answer, but such answers probably support these questions (which are offtopic, as quid already mentioned).